# Updating a user value on login using Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using ASP.NET Identity and trying to update the value `LastAccessed` every time the user logs onto the site. The value is a DateTime type which looks to track the date/time the user was last logged in and updates on each successful login. I am not sure how I could go about doing something like this and would appreciate any in-sight into how I might go about doing this.

### User model

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Identity or do you have your own auth controller? Please make your question more clear...

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I was using Identity. I thought it might be noticeable from the inheritance. I will update the post

Comment: My mistake, actually. I was wondering if you are using the default login page from identity or you created your own auth controller. If you are using the default authentication from Identity, see enet's answer.